# ES6 Object Literal Property Value Shorthand

Tags: ecmascript-6

Using the new shorthand feature in ES6 for object literals, is it possible to use `obj.id` and have it parse as `id: obj.id`? Wondering if I've missed something in the new spec...

```
create(obj) {
    this.connection.send({
        obj.id
    });
    this.add(obj);
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Shorthands do only work for variables, so you should use `{id: obj.id}`.

Answer (score 0):

Although [Bergi response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30347635/220272) is correct, you could create a variable for `id`:

```
create(obj) {
    const { id } = obj;
    this.connection.send({ id });
    this.add(obj);
},
```

For the specific case you mention it's a overload, but on other cases it might be useful.